# Git: Merge Head exists message despite not having any commits staged.

Tags: git

So when i'm trying to do

```
git pull origin master
```

to update my local branch, I get this message:

```
You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you can merge.
```

but when I do

```
git status
```

I don't see any changes staged for commit. I only see a list of changes not staged for commit and untracked files. Any suggestions of what I can do to make this pull successful? Thanks!

Comment: It is impossible to know for sure (without more context).  But it sounds like you have completed the merge and just need to do a `git commit`.

Comment: well, I cloned a repository from github, made some changes to it, but then I realized the github repo was updated. Now my local branch is behind the master branch by 1 commit. I'd like to pull that one in so my local branch is up to date, but it returns the message above. The thing is, I have no files staged for commit. Nothing. Isn't there some sort of reset I could do to start with a clean slate? Something like git reset --merge?

Comment: You could use a `git stash`.  This will temporarily stash your changes and set your head back.  Then do a `git pull`.  Then, `git stash pop` your changes back on top of the updated head.

Comment: okay that sorta put me in the right track. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably you merged a branch, got some conflicts, resolved them but did not commit them. That's the reason for the existence of MERGE HEAD. Now, you can do any of the below 3 things.

1. Add all the files that are not staged for commit. Commit the changes and then perform a pull.
2. Stash your changes. Pull the remote changes. Apply the stash again and continue with your work.
3. git merge --abort if you don't know what merge is in progress and can convince yourself that any partial progress toward resolving that merge can be safely discarded.

All these options will work equally well.

Comment: Option 3 - `git merge --abort` if you don't know what merge is in progress and can convince yourself that any partial progress toward resolving that merge can be safely discarded...

Comment: That is also one of the options. Included in the answer.